# Schema/DTD for Youtube json3 transcript format

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, caption, closed-captions, yt-dlp

I used `yt-dlp --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-format json3 $target_url` to download a Youtube video's captions/transcript.  The JSON starts with this key-value:

```
wireMagic: pb3
```

**Is there a schema definition (JSON Schema, DTD, etc) for this `wireMagic` format?**

I Googled it and also searched the *yt-dlp* and *youtube-dl* Github projects.  But found no details.

The transcript's JSON body contains many cryptic keys, such as `wsWinStyles, mhModeHint, juJustifCode, sdScrollDir, wpWinPositions, apPoint, ahHorPos, avVerPos` etc, which I'd like to understand.

Is it a Jsonified version of a web or pre-web captioning standard?  Or maybe, is it an internal Google/Youtube caption format?